# Check if text contains a string and keep matched words from original text:

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = "Beauty Store is all you need!"
b = "beautystore"
test1 = ''.join(e for e in a if e.isalnum())
test2 = test1.lower() 
test3 = [test2]
match = [s for s in test3 if b in s]
if match != []:
    print(match)
>>>['beautystoreisallyouneed']
```

What I want is: "Beauty Store"

I search for the keyword in the string and I want to return the keyword from the string in the original format (with capital letter and space between, whatever) of the string, but only the part that contains the keyword.

Comment: `if string in line: # do whatever`? What exactly do you want? can you share input and output example?

Comment: So what is the general case here? You have a string and a keyword and search for the keyword in the string, but you also allow variations of that keyword? What kind of variations are allowed?

Comment: Yes... I search for the keyword in the string and I want to return the keyword from the string in the original format (with capital letter and space between, whatever) of the string, but only the part that contains the keyword.

Comment: Does the keyword always occur only once in the string?

Comment: Your issue is that you joining the string making it one chunk then checking if b is in it, so it will return the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keyword only occurs once, this will give you the right solution:

```
a = "Beauty Store is all you need!"
b = "beautystore"

ind = range(len(a))

joined = [(letter, number) for letter, number in zip(a, ind) if letter.isalnum()]

searchtext = ''.join(el[0].lower() for el in joined)

pos = searchtext.find(b)

original_text = a[joined[pos][1]:joined[pos+len(b)][1]]
```

It saves the original position of each letter, joins them to the lowercase string, finds the position and then looks up the original positions again.